# Get indexes from one Array <String> for use it for second Array <String>

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have two `Arrays String`:

```
var labelOne: [String] = ["one", "two", "one", "four", "five"]

var idOne: [String] = ["sdcsadcasdc", "sad213e123wd", "32dsqfdwf", "dsadcdasc", "32rfwec"]
```

Now in program, `"one" = "sdcsadcasdc"`, `"two" = "sad213e123wd"`, `"one" = "32dsqfdwf"`, `"four" = "dsadcdasc"`, `"five = "32rfwec"`.

I have a filter for `labelOne` and put it in another `Array String`:

```
var result = "one"

var searchLabelOne = labelOne.filter { $0.lowercased().contains(result!.lowercased())}
```

I want to get filtered indexes from `searchLabelOne` and use it for get indexes from `idOne`. For this example, I would create `Array String searchIdOne` for `searchLabelOne` with "one" and "one" and he must be:

```
var searchIdOne = ["sdcsadcasdc", "32dsqfdwf"]
```

Please, help

Comment: Why are `labelOne` & `idOne` two array, when it should be one array of custom property? Like a an array of dictionaries, of an array tuples, or an array of custom struct? That's bad design, because as you can see, when modifying one, you need to repeat the same on the second one. It feasable in your case, but if you have arrays (one for each property), changing index of values, etc. It's becoming extra work.

Comment: Still, it can be done with `var searchIdOne = labelOne.indices.filter { labelOne[$0].lowercased().contains(result!.lowercased()) }.map { idOne[$0] }`, but I still argue that's bad idea to continue with two array.

Comment: Zip the arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you want to keep the data structures as the way they are, you can first get the indexes from firstArray.

Then iterate through secondArray to get elements at those indexes.

```
var searchIdOne = labelOne.enumerated().filter( {$0.element == result}).map({ $0.offset}).map({ idOne[$0]})
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip the arrays.

```
var labelOne: [String] = ["one", "two", "one", "four", "five"]
var idOne: [String] = ["sdcsadcasdc", "sad213e123wd", "32dsqfdwf", "dsadcdasc", "32rfwec"]
let result = zip(labelOne, idOne).filter {$0.0.contains("one")}.map {$0.1}
print(result) // ["sdcsadcasdc", "32dsqfdwf"]
```

(Adjust the `filter` predicate as desired, that was only a demo.)